# If statement with "choice" columnn in Dataverse

Tags: if-statement, powerapps, dataverse

I try to create a column in a Dataverse (table) and make a simple if- function, but it does not work.

The column named "Year" has a data type choice.

I created two choices ("Sync with global choice": No) with label: "24", value "1" and label "25", value "2".

I created a new column named "test". Data type "Formula (Preview)". The formula is: "If( Text('Year'.Value)=1, 1, 0), but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**v-jefferni** from Microsoft Powerapps Comunnity answered excellently the question.

In case someone will need it: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Dataverse/If-statement-with-quot-choice-quot-columnn/m-p/2070936#M28506